# Sound output disappeared, only HDMI audio remains

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hardware

At some point last week my sound output disappeared from the sound settings panel in gnome. Only the HDMI output remains.

Abbreviated alsa-info.sh output:

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Mon Oct  9 08:35:32 UTC 2017


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      Precision M4800
Product Version:   01
Firmware Version:  A14
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:        0X3C7N


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DELLABCE:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLK05CC:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33CA:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0401:00/status      13
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/SMO8810:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:01/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:05/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:07/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:09/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:0d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2a/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2b/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2e/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2f/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:30/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:31/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:32/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:33/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:34/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:36/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:37/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:38/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:39/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3a/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3b/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3e/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3f/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:41/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    4.4.0-96-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k4.4.0-96-generic
Library version:    1.1.0
Utilities version:  1.1.0


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 32


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:1b.0 0403: 8086:8c20 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: 1028:05cc
--
01:00.1 0403: 1002:aab0
    Subsystem: 1028:15cc


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 1,32,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x1002aa01
Subsystem Id: 0x00aa0100
Revision Id: 0x100300
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x70]: 32000 44100 48000
    bits [0x2]: 16
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x03 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=3
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=7
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=8
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x08 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x09 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=9
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x08
Node 0x0a [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x0b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=4, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=4, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=4, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=4, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=10
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x0a
Node 0x0c [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=5, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=5, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=5, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=5, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=11
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=06, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Oct  9 10:22 /dev/snd/controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Oct  9 10:22 /dev/snd/hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Oct  9 10:23 /dev/snd/pcmC1D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Oct  9 10:23 /dev/snd/pcmC1D11p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Oct  9 10:30 /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Oct  9 10:23 /dev/snd/pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Oct  9 10:23 /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Oct  9 10:23 /dev/snd/pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Oct  9 10:34 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Oct  9 10:22 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Oct  9 10:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 260 Oct  9 10:22 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Oct  9 10:22 pci-0000:01:00.1 -> ../controlC1


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card 1 [HDMI]

Card hw:1 'HDMI'/'HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 32'
  Mixer name    : 'ATI R6xx HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100300'
  Controls      : 42
  Simple ctrls  : 6
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',5
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

Basically it seems like it recognizes the sound card:     00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

But it doesn't use it as an output. I tried resetting the pulse audio config, but it did nothing.

I booted from a live usb drive and it still doesn't work. I tried resetting the bios as well:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 32
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep -i audio 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav 
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo normal:; aplay -l; echo sudo:; sudo aplay -l 
normal:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
sudo:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The card is recognized with lspci but only hdmi playback devices are recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hardware defect. A replacing the mainboard fixes it.